# MySQL Fulltext search ignores numbers

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, evaluation

Well I have an mysql full text search and the problem is that this query seems to ignore numbers every now and then so the database contains the names for video games like

> Age of Empires
>  Age of Empires 2
>  Age of Empires 3

Now when performing the full text search with a string like **Age of Empires 2**, it will sometimes return Age of Empires or Age of Empires 3 as the first match.

Basically, how can I ensure that numbers in the search string have a high priority in the query/ or later on when evaluating the returned matches?

Comment: Are you sure, "2" is not just too short to count?

Comment: you mean the full text search doesn't count it in?

Comment: @EugenRieck may be right. I think the default settings for full text search have a minimum of 3 characters per item. You should check the mysql settings.

Comment: just checked the settings, minimum as you said is 3 letters, won't be able to change that... is there no other way I can make the numbers count?

Comment: As far as MySQL is concerned, numbers are nothing special. So if you don't index words with a single letter, you won't index the words "2" or "3". You might want to consider another column "generation" or "version" and do some preparsing ... this would also help with "Age of Empires II" and "Warcraft IV"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should use this syntax: `Select * From table1 Where column1 Like 'Age Of Empires 2';`

In my case:

```
mysql> Select * From table1;
 +----------------------+
 |column1               |
 +----------------------+
 |Age Of Empires        |
 |Age Of Empires 2      |
 |Age Of Empires 3      |
 +----------------------+

 mysql> Select * From table1 Where column1 Like 'Age Of Empires 2';
 +----------------------+
 |column1               |
 +----------------------+
 |Age Of Empires 2      |
 +----------------------+
```

Comment: This is just wrong :( if you know exact value, use =, not LIKE. And it does not asnwer the question at all.

Comment: As @jkavalik said this does not answer the question at all.